# MRTG Graph Positoning

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mrtg, bandwidth-measuring

I have deployed MRTG 2.16.2. This is running without any issue, The problem is the graph moves Left to Right as in the image. Can we make it Right to Left. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
Options[mydevice]: growright
```